# How to add stacked icons to anchor links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I've prepared the follow example:

http://jsfiddle.net/NSGRq/1/

Is it possible using CSS only, to underline "Email" whenever the circle icon is hovered?

```
<ul class="inline">
    <li><a class="icon-stack" title="Email" href="mailto:info@info.com">
                <i class="icon-circle icon-stack-base"></i>
                <i class="icon-envelope" style="color: white;"></i> 
        </a><a title="Email" href="mailto:info@info.com">Email</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

also is it possible to remove the duplicate  tags which does exactly the same thing?

```
<a class="icon-stack" title="Email" href="mailto:info@info.com">
<a title="Email" href="mailto:info@info.com">Email</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: only if you want also to underline if the text "Email" is hovered. (At least without changing the markup)

Comment: right, as if they are one

Comment: Yes, it is. But what duplicate tags do you want removed? How about stripping the HTML down to what you want it to be, and *then* ask the question.

Comment: The duplicate mailto links :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what your requirements are, but this is one approach to take.

http://jsfiddle.net/yXWpu/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="inline">
    <li><a class="icon-stack" title="Email" href="mailto:info@info.com">
                <i class="icon-circle icon-stack-base"></i>
                <i class="icon-envelope" style="color: white;"></i> 
        <span class="email-text">Email</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-stack {
    font-size: 32px;
}

a[class^="icon-"], i[class^="icon-"] {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1BA1E2;
}

a[class^="icon-"] .email-text {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin-left: 65px; 
}

a[class^="icon-"]:hover .email-text {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```